# AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'ratio'

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to call ratio() function from the library fuzzywuzzy to match two string and get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'ratio'
```

Has the version changed? I tried to look for other functions within fuzz to see if it exists, but I am unable to find it.

```
import fuzzywuzzy as fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import Levenshtein
fuzz.ratio('Lord of the Rings', 'The Lord of the Rings')
```

Comment: `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz`

Comment: is it just a typo ? or related to module version change ? if it is a version problem, maybe give the versions you were using and the new versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change import to:

```
from fuzzywuzzy as fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
```

Answer (score 5):

`ratio` is a method of [`fuzzywuzzy.fuzz`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/778162c5a73256745eb6ae22f925bc2dbcf7c894/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py#L24). Use:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
```

Then you can use:

```
fuzz.ratio('Lord of the Rings', 'The Lord of the Rings')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy), you can see that you are not importing fuzzywuzzy correctly.

Instead of `import fuzzywuzzy as fuzz` you should use `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz`

Basically, you have two ways to do it. Either:

```
import fuzzywuzzy as <something>
<something>.fuzz.ratio(...)
```

or
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    fuzz.ratio(...)

Answer (score 0):

The readme file over at https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy states that the way to use `fuzzywuzzy` is:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
```

The way you have done it (`import fuzzy-wuzzy as fuzz`) means you would need another level in your calling hierarchy, `fuzz.fuzz.blah` instead of just `fuzz.blah`.

So the answer is to either use that extra level, or import it in the documented manner.